# Conditional Probability question given probability that child has brown hair is 1/4

Tags: probability

The probability that a child has brown hair is $\frac{1}{4}$. Assume independence between children. Consider a family with 3 children.

a) If it is known that at least one child has brown hair, what is the probability that at least two children have brown hair?

My solution -
$\frac{P(at least 2 brown hair  \mid  at least 1 brown hair)}{P(at least 1 brown hair)}$ 
= $\frac{(\frac{1}{4})^2}{(\frac{1}{4})^3} = \frac{1}{4}$

Is this correct?

b) If it is known that the youngest child has brown hair, what is the probability that at least two children have brown hair?

I have no idea how to solve this problem when given info about the youngest child.

Comment: Almost everything about your attempt for the first problem was incorrect.  Lets start smaller... What is the probability that at least one has brown hair?  $\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{1}{4}$ is the probability that they all have brown hair, not the probability that at least one does.  (*Maybe try answering the question of what the probability is that all three have hair a color different than brown?*)

Comment: As an aside, since you only told us about the probability of *boys* having brown hair and nothing about girls, I suppose that the family has only boy children?

Comment: Sorry updated to child and not boy.

Comment: Would it be $\frac{1}{4}$ * $(\frac{3}{4})^2$ + $(\frac{1}{4})^2$ * $\frac{3}{4}$ + $(\frac{3}{4})^3$  ?  
Also I'm not sure if my numerator is correct.

Comment: $\frac{1}{4}\times \frac{3}{4}\times\frac{3}{4}$ is the probability that the youngest child has brown hair and the older two children both have hair a different color than brown.  At least one child has brown hair would also have included if the middle child had brown hair and neither of the other two, the eldest had brown and neither of the other two, the two youngest both having brown hair, all children having brown hair, etc... Recall, "At least one child has brown hair" is the opposite event of "No children have brown hair."

Answer (score 2):

Your answer for a) is not correct.

The probability that at least one child has brown hair is the complement of the probability that their hair are all not brown:
$$p_1:=1-\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^3.$$
The probability that at least two children have brown hair is
$$p_2=\underbrace{3\cdot \frac{3}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{4^2}}_{BBN,BNB,NBB}+\underbrace{\frac{1}{4^3}}_{BBB}.$$

So the answer for a) is $\frac{p_2}{p_1}=\frac{10}{37}$ which is greater than $\frac{1}{4}$.

Now for b), we may assume that the first child is the youngest. So
$$p_1=P(\{BNN,BBN,BNB,BBB\})\quad \text{and}\quad
p_2=P(\{BBN,BNB,BBB\}).$$
So what is $\frac{p_2}{p_1}$ in this case?

Answer (score 0):

#### a) your solution is wrong. You should write:

$P(\text{at least two}) = 3C2 \cdot 0.75 \cdot 0.25^2 + 0.25^3$

(multiply because you don't care which child is brown haired)

$P(\text{at least one}) = 1 - 0.75^3$

$P(\text{two when known one}) = \frac{P(\text{at least two})}{P(\text{at least one})$

#### b) Now, we don't multiply.

$P(\text{youngest brown headed}) = 0.25$

$P(\text{at least two exclude youngest}) = 2 \cdot 0.75 \cdot 0.25^2 + 0.25^3$

$P(\text{answer}) = \dfrac{P(\text{at least two exclude youngest})}{ P(\text{youngest brown headed})}$

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.